# how can i configure nanorc for nano version 1.2.4

Tags: nano

i was trying to configure my nanorc file to code c in nano on the company server, i tried some examples that i found on internet but i got a lot of errors. in a page i found that i can see some other examples in the /usr/share/doc/nano/examples directory, but it does not exist.

this is one example that i tried to use:

```
syntax "C" "\.(c(c|pp|xx|ec)?|C)$" "\.(h(h|pp|xx)?|H)$" "\.ii?$" "\.(def)$" "\.ino" "\.ec"
magic "^(C|C\+\+) (source|program)"
comment "//"
color brightred "\<[A-Z_][0-9A-Z_]+\>"
color green "\<(float|double|bool|char|wchar_t|int|short|long|sizeof|enum|void|static|const|struct|union|typedef|extern|(un)?sign$
```

and i get this message when i try to open a file with nano
`command magic not understood command comment not understood` 
i think this syntax is not compatible with this version of nano, but i don't have any example of the compatible syntax

Comment: i think,the syntax file you're trying to use may not be compatible with the version of Nano that you're using!

Comment: do you know where i can find the correct syntax for this version?